# How do I manually uninstall the Developer Tools?

Tags: macos, xcode

I installed the Developer Tools way back in Tiger or Leopard and I'd like to uninstall them now. I have Xcode 4.0.2. How do I uninstall them manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, simply run the following in Terminal:

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Where `<Xcode>` is the default installation of Xcode, typically:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I don't have an uninstall Perl script.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. What version of Xcode are you running? 4.3? If that's the case, then just trash the Xcode.app in /Applications. It doesn't install anything else; everything is localized inside the .app now. Hence the lack of an uninstall script (none is required).

Comment: If you are running an older version <3. Check inside the /Developer folder. There should always be a script. And that won't get removed if you update your OS.

Comment: I am running Xcode 4.0.2.

Comment: @daviesgeek List the contents of /Developer/Library please.

Comment: So sorry I haven't got back to you on this. I must have missed the comment. I looked in `/Developer/Library` and I feel pretty stupid now. I *do* have a script in the folder and it did work. Thanks so much for your answer and all your help!!

Comment: @daviesgeek NP. Glad it helped and you got it sorted. It's possible to remove it manually but it's far from a trivial process.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your OP, I am assuming you are running pre-Lion Xcode. This is covered in the documentation that comes with the Developer Tools install:
`/Developer/About Xcode`

> **Uninstalling Xcode Developer Tools**
>   To uninstall Xcode developer tools on the boot volume along with the  directory, from a Terminal window type:
>   $ sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
>
> To remove the underlying developer content on the boot volume, but leave the  directory and supporting files untouched, from a Terminal window type:
>   $ sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools -- mode=systemsupport
>   To just remove the UNIX development support on the boot volume, but leave the  directory and supporting files untouched, from a Terminal window type:
>   $ sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=unixdev
>
> Finally, to just uninstall the  directory you can simply drag it to the trash, or from a Terminal window type:
>   $ sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=xcodedir
>
> NOTE: The uninstaller that ships with previous versions of the Xcode developer tools will not clean everything off of your system properly. You should use the one installed with these Xcode developer tools.

Pleae super-double check that this documentation either exists with your installation or is the **same** as your installation before you act. As with any such commands, precision and compatibility are **critical**.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just have to remove the `/Developer` folder (especially if you have already installed version 4.3 or later of Xcode). [The Xcode section of the Apple Developer Support Center](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) actually tells you to do this (emphasis mine).

> ### I've installed the latest version of Xcode from the Mac App Store, but a previous version of Xcode (4.2.1 or earlier) keeps launching. What should I do?
>
> ---
>
> To run the latest version of Xcode, make sure you are launching Xcode.app from the Applications folder. Xcode 4.3 and later is packaged on the Mac App Store as a single application and installs in your Applications folder as Xcode.app.
>
> **Previous versions of Xcode placed the tools and frameworks in the Developer folder. You can delete the older version of Xcode by dragging the Developer folder to the trash.**

This is reiterated in [New Features in Xcode 4.3](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html) (emphasis mine).

> **The simplification afforded by repackaging Xcode 4.3 as a single app bundle eliminates the need for the `/Developer` directory containing prior versions of Xcode.** As a result, **the Install Xcode application and the `uninstall-devtools` command line script are also no longer needed.**
>
> **Note:** The first time you run Xcode 4.3, you are prompted with a dialog to delete the Install Xcode application from the Applications directory if one is resident, and to remove any older installation of Xcode (Figure 4). These actions are optional, **Xcode 4.3 can co-exist with older installations of Xcode on the same Mac.** Some operations may require an administrator password to enable them if you switch from one version of Xcode to another.
>
> **Figure 4**  Option to remove older versions of Xcode
>
> [image: Xcode screenshot]
>
> If you choose not to delete these items on the first launch of Xcode 4.3, **you can remove the `/Developer` folder and the Install Xcode application by dragging them to the Trash at any time.**

Answer (score -2):

cd Library
sudo rm -rf Developer/

Comment: This does not work for Tiger see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308943/how-do-i-uninstall-the-command-line-tools-for-xcode for newer