# How do I uninstall the command line tools for Xcode?

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, development

We have a bunch of Mac at work that no longer require Xcode or command line tools so we'd like to remove them so the compilers aren't hanging around and we don't have to keep updating them when updates arrive.

[Before Xcode was in the Mac App Store, there ware install and uninstall scripts (perl in /Developer) to remove the tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44597/how-do-i-manually-uninstall-the-developer-tools), but now that Xcode is an app store app you are left with the tools if you ever install them.

Can we clean this other than wiping the OS for macs running 10.10 and newer?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Delete this one folder:

```
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

This uninstall process is [documented officially by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_CAN_I_UNINSTALL_THE_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS_).

If you have installed these tools another way or have prompts to upgrade them, consider searching for files named like **/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools.bom** since that may be a receipt for a past installation of the tools that needs to be removed. I have never seen one of these files, but wanted to [link to this other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328089/5472) in case it helps others. Note, these files do not remove the tools, they may govern the prompt that dev tools are in need of an update.

- [Removing uninstalled Command Line Tools from AppStore updates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328034/removing-uninstalled-command-line-tools-from-appstore-updates)

Comment: However whenever there's a command line tools update, the App Store keeps showing up to update it.

Comment: Long time ago I used a DMG (needed to install an *older* version of the command line tools, but that's another story). Now I can't seem to get rid of it.

Comment: Aah @adib - That makes sense. This question was for a new / recent install where you only go to the App Store and install Xcode - that will download the tools for you without leaving a receipt in my experience.

Comment: Hence, what would be the answer to *really* uninstalling Command Line Tools?

Comment: @adib - It depends how they were installed. I’m trying to document how to remove them for sone specific install path, not all possible ones. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312272/5472

Comment: @adlib: I had the same problem, just managed to fix it by deleting the bom files from `/System/Library/Receipts`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328034/removing-uninstalled-command-line-tools-from-appstore-updates/328089#328089 Perhaps that'll help you as well.

Comment: Receipts may be found in `/Library/Apple/System/Library/Receipts` ...

Comment: To delete com.apple.pkg.CLTools* files from /Library/Apple/System/Library/Receipts, you must boot into Recovery and mount your Macintosh HD - Data volume.

Comment: `rm -rf $(xcode-select --print-path)`. However, if you use `git` you need the cmd tools. Otherwise, `git` cannot be installed.

Comment: this actually endless popups msg of "Git requires developertools to be installed would you like to install it now ? " I just can't get out of it