# Beta Command Line Tools offered as update—why?

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, software-update, beta

Today the App Store is offering me the Command Line Tools for Xcode 10.0 beta 1.

[image]

I do not recall ever signing up as a beta tester for any Apple software. Why do I get this update and how can I prevent such beta software from being accidentally installed on my system?

I have macOS 10.13.5 and Xcode 9.4. I also have MacPorts with clang 6.0 (newer than the one in Xcode, but it shouldn't interfere).

---

**Update 2019-06-04:** It is happening again, this time it is offering "Command Line Tools beta 1 for Xcode 11.0". This seems to be a mistake on Apple's part again (see the accepted answer).

**Update 2020-09-15:** Again with "Command Line Tools beta 5 for Xcode 12.0".

Comment: Anyone reading this that uses developer tools head warning -- This will break everything, especially homebrew. I had to reinstall XCode to reinstall old tools just to get my dev tools working again.

Comment: @Jahhein Updated my answer with a link to the removal package.

Comment: @grg good looking out for others! I'm actually surprised you managed to find them. All I could find was the already distributed beta tools.

Comment: FYI: This is happening yet again for "Command Line Tools beta 1 for Xcode 14.1" in macOS Monterey 12.6 (21G115) this morning. *sigh*...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apple has also now fixed the same issue which occurred with macOS 10.14 Mojave offering CLTools for macOS 10.15 Catalina. For a short time, the 10.14 catalog included 10.15's tools, but this has since been removed from this catalog and only included in the beta catalog.

- https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz

[image]

A removal package has not been provided for removing the 10.15 tools specifically this year. You can try removing the tools using the removal package for 10.14 or removing them completely, then reinstall them:

- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/11/13/041-71563/s1da971g95kch5ljsghwjufij12crr2o5b/CLTools_macOS_DevSDK_Remove_1014.pkg
- [How do I uninstall the command line tools for Xcode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/308943/37797)

---

Apple fixed the issue for macOS 10.13 High Sierra. **Refresh the updates with ⌘R** and the update should disappear.

This was a bug on Apple's part. Apple has incorrectly released this update to everyone, not just those on a beta upgrade path.

If the update is still shown, you can hide it by right-clicking and choosing Hide Update.

[image: Hide Update from list]

If you've installed the update and realised your tools are broken, you can remove these tools using `CLTools_macOS_SDK_Remove_1014.pkg` from Apple:

- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/01/53/091-65367/h0b7b20hoylsqj7pih1htv5b9oa9y4z4gq/CLTools_macOS_SDK_Remove_1014.pkg

---

The update was incorrectly provided in the default software update catalog on High Sierra: https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz.

The update is provided for beta and developers in their associated catalogs:

- https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.13beta-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz
- https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.13seed-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz

```
<dict>
    <key>Digest</key>
    <string>82bddd90f3152da26424d8c6fb7264763a3eee78</string>
    <key>Size</key>
    <integer>26082625</integer>
    <key>MetadataURL</key>
    <string>https://swdist.apple.com/content/downloads/01/53/091-65367/h0b7b20hoylsqj7pih1htv5b9oa9y4z4gq/CLTools_SDK_macOS1014.pkm</string>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/01/53/091-65367/h0b7b20hoylsqj7pih1htv5b9oa9y4z4gq/CLTools_SDK_macOS1014.pkg</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: So, there is nothing broken on my system, and everyone else is getting this update. Just ignore it until Apple fixes it.

Comment: If you (re-)run software updates, it should be gone now. Looks like Apple's fixed things.

Comment: @Michael Confirmed, the entry was removed from the catalog. Edited answer for prominency, thanks

Comment: I'm getting this again ... I assume another mess up on the part of Apple? Or is something really broken on my machine this time? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUYUK.png

Comment: @Szabolcs They've gone and done it again! See update; same strategy as last year: ignore it or Hide Update until Apple fixes the catalog.

Comment: @grg what's the proper way to ignore the update on macOS Mojave? `softwareupdate --ignore "Command Line Tools beta 1 for Xcode-11.0"` doesn't seem to help; nor there is Ignore button in GUI.

Comment: What's the URL of the default Mojave catalog?

Comment: @xilopaint I've added this to my answer

Comment: At least on mojave CLTools_SDK_macOS1015 is breaking all mono applications. 
Seems that they changed something in the mono lib.

Remove instructions (deleting Library/Developer/CLTools) did not work. Also uninstalling xcode seems not to work. 

There seem to be some artifacts left that break mono.

Answer (score 10):

As this bug also happens in Monterey with Command Line Tools beta 3 for Xcode 14.1 sometimes, here is a workaround:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/.beta
```

When the beta is already installed, reinstall:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
xcode-select --install
```

Then check for tools updates (and install if yes):

```
softwareupdate --list
softwareupdate --install -a
```