# Command Line Tools beta 1 for Xcode 11.0 offered as an update in the current latest public release of macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: mojave, xcode, software-update, beta

I am running the current latest public release of macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132) with the current latest public release of Xcode 10.2.1 installed.

When opening System Preferences app → Software Update, I am offered an update for Command Line Tools beta 1 for Xcode 11.0.

[image]

[image]

I am pretty sure that I am not currently enrolled into Apple Developer Program. Neither have I knowingly or unknowingly installed any developer/public beta software profile on my Mac.

Why is this beta release of CLI tools offered as an update? Should I install it? How do I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this beta release of CLI tools offered as an update?

This update is mistakenly released by Apple for everyone. This has happened last year as well when the betas for macOS Mojave and Xcode 10.0 were released for developers by Apple during WWDC 2018.

See the Q&A from last year (2018):

- [Beta Command Line Tools offered as update—why?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327115/beta-command-line-tools-offered-as-update-why)

> Should I install it?

No. You should not install it as it is not meant for you.

> How do I remove it?

Simply ignore the update and it should go away automatically.

Comment: Thanks. How do I remove the update if I installed it?