# pkgutil --forget: Error "No such file or directory"

Tags: software-update, macos, pkg

I'm getting a path-location error.

```
$ pkgutil --forget com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
Unknown error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.bom” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.bom, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb0cdc0bd70 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}.
Forgot package 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' on '/'.
```

The receipt data I want to discard is in `/System/Library/Receipts/`.

```
$ ls /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTool*
/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.bom
/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.plist
/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_OSX1012.bom
/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_OSX1012.plist
/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_macOS1013.bom
/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_macOS1013.plist
/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_macOSSDK.bom
/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_SDK_macOSSDK.plist
```

Why is `pkgutil` looking for the bill of materials (BOM) file in `/var/db/receipts/`?

Note: I've already deleted the folder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

Motivation: [Removing uninstalled Command Line Tools from AppStore updates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328034/removing-uninstalled-command-line-tools-from-appstore-updates)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the solution is the same for you as it was for me, which already is written in my post which you've linked to ([Removing uninstalled Command Line Tools from AppStore updates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328034/removing-uninstalled-command-line-tools-from-appstore-updates)).

Boot into recovery to disable SIP, then trash the files, then enable SIP again. Hopefully that works for you as well (seems to be exactly the same problem as I had).

EDIT: perhaps your actual question is why it's looking in the wrong path for the receipts. I have no idea, I'd like to know that myself. :)