# Removing old versions of XCode Command-Line Tools on macOS 12

Tags: terminal, command-line, xcode

I recently got a new M1 MacBook which I migrated to using Migration Assistant. As part of the migration, the old XCode command-line tools seem to have made their way over, install receipts and all; now, the Software Update system preference always shows there being updates available on multiple versions of the XCode Command-Line Tools. Every time I tell the system to update, it seems to redownload and reinstall the updates for all three versions, but then it once again prompts to update. Similar things happen if I use the commandline `softwareupdate` tool:

```
grace:~ $ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
grace:~ $ softwareupdate --install -a
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloading Command Line Tools for Xcode
Downloading Command Line Tools beta 4 for Xcode
Downloading Command Line Tools for Xcode
Downloaded Command Line Tools for Xcode
Downloaded Command Line Tools for Xcode
Downloaded Command Line Tools beta 4 for Xcode
Installing Command Line Tools for Xcode, Command Line Tools beta 4 for Xcode, Command Line Tools for Xcode
```

I'd like to completely reinstall the XCode Command-Line Tools so that software update no longer attempts to update it, and so that I can properly reinstall. However, if I just `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, the system still thinks they're installed, and for example `xcode-select --install` tells me that they're already installed, and `xcode-select --reset` has no effect on this.

What do I need to do on macOS 12 to completely remove the XCode Command-Line Tools so that I can do a fresh reinstall, short of reformatting my whole laptop?

Comment: This might help:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328034/removing-uninstalled-command-line-tools-from-appstore-updates/328089#328089

Comment: Unfortunately that isn’t where macOS stores the developer tools update information anymore.

Comment: I have this exact same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: I wonder @SeverusD if [this hokey pokey](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364259/5472) is needed now.

Comment: It eventually stopped happening for me but I can’t remember if I did anything myself. I want to say it was just waiting for a macOS update that did the trick. Not a satisfying resolution, I know…

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the receipt from /Library/Apple/System/Library/Receipts as [described in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/425824/5472) first.

If that fails, this [multi step “hokey pokey” type process might help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364259/5472). I would try to avoid messing with SIP personally as it doesn’t make sense this install would wedge itself in that hard.

In the mean time, applying updates might help rebuild the database or obsolete all the old command line tools if you don’t mind keeping on the recent update train.

Comment: As I stated in the comments, I didn’t find any receipts in that directory.

Comment: If the hokey pokey doesn’t work, you might have to live with it since an erase and reinstall is the way to make a clean receipts database and you’ve ruled that out @fluffy