# Can't Remove macOS Command Line Tools Update

Tags: mac

How can I stop this update from trying to install on my Mac? I deleted /Library/Developer and /Library/Updates already. I don't have Xcode or Homebrew installed. What else can I try?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/425824/37797

Comment: See the below. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/446748

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I deleted all the files in /Library/Apple/System/Library/Receipts. Deleting them in /System/Library/Receipts didn't work.